# PrimeFaces / jQuery: Keys not working on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, primefaces

I have a website that has a `<p:fieldset>` for search parameters. Upon search in the `oncomplete` it is collapsed via `PF('fieldsetFilter').toggle();`. The page has a `<p:dialog>` which has `<p:calendar>` elements.
At some point (I didn't figure out until now how to reproduce it reliably) the following problems occur:

- some input components within the fieldset cannot be focused by a click
- these input components can be reached via tab key, show the blinking
  cursor but upon key strokes nothing is entered
- the calendar popup within the dialog doesn't open anymore on click; I can still enter a
  date manually
- other input components before, between and after the not working ones work as expected
- hotkeys don't work (F12, Ctrl + S, Ctrl + U etc.)

The problem is resolved by refreshing the page.

I was thinking of some JS to be part of the problem and tried setting break points on some `preventDefaul()` lines in custom .js files. Upon F12 nothing happens. I compared the generated HTML of a working and non-working version via diff and didn't find anything significant.

When logging keyboard events and typing in a non working input component there are more (+7 keydown, +5 keyup) events, all related to the input component's id and without a .js file on the right side.

The input component has multiple, additonal `mouseup` events shown in firefox's developer tools. Deactivating these events doesn't change the behaviour.

What would be rational steps to narrow the problem down?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: This was helpful. While narrowing it down I found a form in a form that held a `<p:poll>`and caused the problem.